# Laravel Excel - File does not exist

Tags: excel, laravel

Laravel Excel 3.1
Laravel 8.75
PHP 7.4

Hello! I am using Laravel Excel package (https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel) to export xlsx and csv files with text and images inside. I do from a view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          @foreach ($order->order_items as $item)
              <tr>              
                 <td><img src="{{ public_path('storage/' . $item->product->image) }}"</td> 
                  <td>{{ $item->product->name }}</td> 
                  <td>{{ $item->product->sku }}</td> 
              </tr>
          @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my local environment there is no problem but in production I get the following message:

File http://expo.zlestore.com/storage/products/rvhmSggWJquRpQvYLUMUvXEeUJzhlBx0xhDd4qal.jpg does not exist

I already run the storage link command and it is working. If I go to that link I see there is an image, the file actually exists but I can't export the file.. I tried different ways but without successs:

```
1) src="{{ Storage::url($item->product->image) }}">
2) src="{{ public_path('storage/' . $item->product->image) }}">
3) src='https://expo.zlestore.com/storage/' . $item->product->image>
4) src="{{asset('storage/'.$item->product->image)}}"
```

Could you help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

If I delete the img tag line everything works fine.
I expect the xlsx file to be exported correctly with images inside.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The correct way is

```
<img src="{{storage_path('app/public/'.$item->product->image)}}">
```